# Flutter How to add a Linear Timer

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Need to know how to add a linear timer that has a timer with second that my the api returns, usually its 60secs but it can change depending on the quiz question, so i need it to be linear with stars on it so if the player finishes the quiz before 20 secs he gets 3 stars, after 20 secs till 40 he gets 2 stars, and after 40 to 60 he gets 1 star. I need it to be like the image here at the top of the screen [Timer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbHVb.png)

```
                            Widget build(BuildContext context) {
print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 23.h,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEF6E98),
        title: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 50),
              child: Text(
                'Rendit Fjalet',
                style: GoogleFonts.fredokaOne(
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25.0.sp,
                  color: Colors.white,
                )),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 60, bottom: 60),
                child: Text(
                  '- Fjala numer:  -',
                  style: GoogleFonts.fredokaOne(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18.0.sp,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )),
                ),
              ))
        ])),
    body: FutureBuilder<List<QuizInfo>?>(
        future: futureData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<QuizInfo>? data = snapshot.data;
            return Stack(children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage(
                          'assets/background.PNG',
                        ),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LinearProgressIndicator` widget, to help you draw the count-down timer. Just pass in a `double` between 0 to 1, to its `value` property.

You can see the [full doc and example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/LinearProgressIndicator-class.html) here.

As for the stars, you just have to draw them separately. You can use either `Icon` or `Image` widget.

Comment: Okay ill try it out and let you know